# Google cloud dataflow limit of steps/transformations

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-dataprep

I am working with a complex Google Cloud Dataprep process. In order to make it work properly, I designed different modules and then linked them (with referenced datasets).

If I execute those modules separately they work properly, but when executing them together it gives an error and never starts working.

> Creating the Dataflow job failed unexpectedly.

Do you know if there is a limitation in the number of recipes in Dataprep or the number of jobs/transformations in Dataflow?

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: the error it gives is: "Creating the Dataflow job failed unexpectedly"

Comment: It's a vague error that I have certainly received when trying to run multiple data prep jobs concurrently - I think the stack driver trace said "maximum workers from pool exceeded" or something like that. In that instance, I re-ran whichever jobs failed.

Where you have your 'modules' daisy-chained in separate Flows but the results are referenced by subsequent jobs I was under the impression that it compiled it into a single Dataflow job and therefore wouldn't encounter the error for the same reason.

Check the Console for the specific error, it gives more detail than Dataprep itself.